# How do I chop down trees in Paradise Island?

Tags: paradise-island

I have Paradise Island by Game Insight on my android phone. How can I chop down trees so I can get wood to fix the bridge to the other part of the Island?

Answer (score 1):

You must buy luxury palms and then demolish them. Its very expensive b-se cost of the palm is 5000$ + demolisation about 2000$ and on 5 planted palms you get about 1-2 wood only :/